# Possible to get "old" time stamp behaviour?

Tags: wget, zip

When downloading a file or e.g. unzipping one, the time stamp is not set to when the file appeared on my harddisk, which is what I want.

See this example

```
~$ wget https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
~$ stat logo3w.png 
  File: `logo3w.png'
  Size: 7007        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 17040834    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      ss)   Gid: ( 1000/      ss)
Access: 2012-07-25 10:58:26.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2012-04-02 04:13:37.000000000 +0200
Change: 2012-07-25 10:58:26.254385152 +0200
 Birth: -
~$ ll logo3w.png 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ss ss 7007 Apr  2 04:13 logo3w.png
```

This behaviour is "new" and has happens within the last couple of years.

**Question**

Is it possible to disable this, so when a file is written to disk, it gets the time stamp when I did it?

Comment: This happens because the application you used to download or unzip explicitly resets the file's date. It does this because that's the useful behavior most of the time. I doubt your assertion that this didn't use to happen: this behavior doesn't tend to change over time, are you sure you were using the same application a couple of years ago?

Comment: @Gilles: For example, wget 1.12 we have at work does not have the --no-use-serer-timestamps option. It resets the file's date, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the wget man page:

> `--no-use-server-timestamps`
>
> Don't set the local file's timestamp by the one on the server.
>
> By default, when a file is downloaded, its timestamps are set to match those from the remote file. This allows the use of `--timestamping` on subsequent invocations of `wget`. However, it is sometimes useful to base the local file's timestamp on when it was actually downloaded; for that purpose, the `--no-use-server-timestamps` option has been provided.

`unzip` also has a `-DD` option to skip  restoration  of timestamps for extracted items.

From `man unzip`:

> `-D`
>
> skip  restoration  of timestamps for extracted items.
>
> Normally, unzip tries to restore all meta-information for extracted  items that  are supplied in the Zip archive (and do not require privileges or impose a security risk).
>
> By specifying  `-D`, `unzip` is told to suppress restoration of timestamps for directories explicitly created from Zip archive entries.  [...]
>
> The duplicated option `-DD` forces suppression of timestamp restoration  for  all  extracted entries (files and directories).  This option results in setting the timestamps for all extracted entries to the current time.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [How to create an RPM package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package):

> add the text `timestamping = on` to `~/.wgetrc`

so I'd imagine doing

```
timestamping = off
```

will do it

Comment: The correct command is `use_server_timestamps = off`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html ,  while `timestamping` only used to decide whether download if the file exists based on timestamp, see https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping.html#Time_002dStamping . Note also a `~/.wgetrc` sample can be copying from `/etc/wgetrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any such option for my version of `wget`. Maybe you can just `touch` everything you download?